# Detetive: Dúvidas

Tags: python-3.x

Boa tarde estimados! Tenho uma grande dúvida numa atividade de Python3! 
Segue o link da atividade: http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~mc102/labs/roteiro-lab06.html

Primeiramente, mandarei meu código para que entendam como pensei e como fiz (sem considerar a parte de casos resolvidos, pessoas mortas, etc)

```
#-* coding utf-8-*-

N=int(input())
if N<0 or N>100:
    print("Valor inválido na entrada.")
else:
    caso={}
    deceased={}
    killer={}
    xeroque={}
    for n in range(N):
        assassino,vítima,detetive=input().split()
        caso[assassino]=["assassino"]
        caso[vítima]=["vítima"]
        caso[detetive]=["detetive"]
        deceased[vítima]=["vítima"]
        killer[assassino]=["assassino"]
        xeroque[detetive]=["detetive"]
        if assassino in detetive:
            caso[assassino]=caso[detetive]
for i in sorted(caso):
    print(60*"-")

    if i==assassino:        #ASSASSINO
        if i in deceased:
            print(str(i)+" (in memoriam):"+" assassino(a).")        
        elif i in xeroque:
            print(str(i)+" :"+" detetive.")
            break
        elif i in killer:
            print(str(i)+":"+" assassino(a).")  

    elif i==vítima:     #Vítima
        if i in killer:
            print(str(i)+" (in memoriam):"+" assassino(a).")
        elif i in xeroque:
            print(str(i)+" (in memoriam):"+" detetive.")
        else:
            print(str(i)+" (in memoriam):"+" vítima inocente.")

    elif i==detetive:   # Detetive
        if i in killer:     
            print(str(i)+":"+" detetive.")
        elif i in deceased:
            print(str(i)+" (in memoriam):"+" detetive.")
        elif i in xeroque:
            print(str(i)+":"+" detetive.")

print(sorted(caso.items()))
print(killer.items())
print(deceased.items())
```

Até o momento tenho isso feito. Porém, logo no terceiro teste (Maria Cicero Bianca e Maria Alan Bianca) dá errado, uma vez que a saída fica assim:

> 2
>   maria cicero bianca
>
> ### maria alan bianca
>
> ### alan (in memoriam): vítima inocente.
>
> ### bianca: detetive.
>
> ---
>
> maria: assassino(a).

Nao consigo entender pq o programa nao lê o cícero, uma vez que eu imprimo o dicionario de caso e de vítimas e ele consta como vítima em ambos!

Comment: Uma sugestão geral que eu daria é de tentar separar partes do código que repetem em funções. Isso vai deixar o código mais claro e mais fácil de debugar.